# omen gaming hub gpu temperature display error

Tags: hp

In omen gaming hub application, my graphics card temperature appears as "--"

[image: OMEN Gaming Hub screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried a different monitoring program?

Comment: Did you previously see a temperature there? What has changed since last time you saw a temp listed? What research have you done and what have you tried regarding figuring out this or resolving it yourself?

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't tried any other imaging program because this program is the main program of my computer and I control the power settings through it.

Comment: @music2myear The temperature has not been visible for a while. I just discovered this site and opened a topic here. I don't know exactly how long the temperature has not been displayed. As a solution, I searched on the internet and tried reinstalling the app, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Interception - The software you are using either has a software bug or a hardware bug.  Unless you can confirm whether it's a software or hardware bug, there isn't enough information to diagnose your issue as you have currently presented it.